# Creating an Elastic search image. Issue with non-root user and image size

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

**Solution - Used Multi-stage build file to reduce the size significantly.  solution pasted below**

**Edit**: Already played with default elastic search image, But the purpose of this exercise is to learn working of Dockerfile. That is how i noticed my image being much larger (2.5G) than official image (742 M)

New to dockers/containers landscape ( was using vagrants till now ) .

To get better understanding of Dockerfile working, decided to create an ES image ( similar to ones i created in the past for a vagrant box ) .

Can someone help in reviewing the docker file and answer following issues being encountered.

1. Running ES as root is not allowed and running it from /home/newuser gives following error.

   What am i missing here ? How should i create a new user/group to resolve this issue.

```
newuser@9f5820d430eb:~$ elasticsearch
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: starting java failed with [1]
output:
[0.000s][error][logging] Error opening log file 'logs/gc.log': Permission denied
[0.001s][error][logging] Initialization of output 'file=logs/gc.log' using options 'filecount=32,filesize=64m' failed.
error:
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

2. The dockerfile is installing JDK and ES but the images size is over 2GB. Can this be reduced . Found something called multi-stage images. not sure how to fit that concept in my dockerfile.
3. In vagrant provisions i update paths to /etc/environment.
   Should this be done for containers ? I am not sure if it adds any value.

**Docerkfile -**

```
# Base image stage 1
FROM ubuntu

#MAINTAINER demo@gmail.com
LABEL maintainer="demo@foo.com"
############################################
###  Install openjava
############################################

#RUN apt-get update
ARG JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
ARG JDK_PACKAGE=openjdk-14.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

# setup paths
ENV JAVA_HOME $JAVA_HOME

# Setup JAVA_HOME, this is useful for docker commandline
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin


## write to environment file for all future sessions
#  sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/" >> /etc/environment'
#  sudo /bin/sh -c '.  /etc/environment ; echo PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH" >> /etc/environment'


## download open java
#  ADD https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14.0.2/205943a0976c4ed48cb16f1043c5c647/12/GPL/$JDK_PACKAGE /
#  ADD $JDK_PACKAGE /
COPY $JDK_PACKAGE /

RUN mkdir -p $JAVA_HOME/ && \
    tar -zxf /$JDK_PACKAGE --strip-components 1  -C $JAVA_HOME  && \
    rm -f /$JDK_PACKAGE


############################################
###  Install elastic search
############################################

ARG ES_HOME=/opt/elasticsearch
ARG ES_PACKAGE=elasticsearch-7.10.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

# setup paths
ENV ES_HOME $ES_HOME

# Setup ES_HOME, this is useful for docker commandline
ENV PATH $PATH:$ES_HOME/bin

##write to environment file for all future sessions
#sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo ES_HOME="/opt/elasticsearch/" >> /etc/environment'
#sudo /bin/sh -c '.  /etc/environment ; echo PATH="$ES_HOME/bin:$PATH" >> /etc/environment'

## download es
#  ADD https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.10.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz  /
#  ADD $JDK_PACKAGE /
COPY $ES_PACKAGE /

RUN mkdir -p $ES_HOME/  && \
    tar -zxf /$ES_PACKAGE --strip-components 1  -C $ES_HOME  && \
    rm -f /$ES_PACKAGE

# Mount elasticsearch.yml config
ADD config/elasticsearch.yml /elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
#ADD config/elasticsearch.yml /


############################################
###  Others
############################################


# Expose ports
EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 9300


## give permission to entire elasticsearch setup directory
RUN chmod 755 -R $ES_HOME
RUN chmod 755 -R $JAVA_HOME
RUN chmod 755 -R /var/log

# add non root user
RUN useradd newuser --create-home --shell /bin/bash
RUN echo 'newuser:newpassword' | chpasswd
RUN adduser newuser sudo
USER newuser
WORKDIR /home/newuser


# Define default command.
#CMD ["elasticsearch"]
```

**Solution -**

Multi stage build file with non-root user

```
ARG JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
ARG JDK_PACKAGE=openjdk-14.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
ARG ES_HOME=/opt/elasticsearch
ARG ES_PACKAGE=elasticsearch-7.10.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz


#MAINTAINER demo@gmail.com
#LABEL maintainer="demo@foo.com"


############################################
###  Install openjava
############################################

# Base image stage 1
FROM ubuntu as jdk

ARG JAVA_HOME
ARG JDK_PACKAGE

WORKDIR /opt/

## download open java
#  ADD https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14.0.2/205943a0976c4ed48cb16f1043c5c647/12/GPL/$JDK_PACKAGE /
#  ADD $JDK_PACKAGE /
COPY $JDK_PACKAGE .

RUN mkdir -p $JAVA_HOME/ && \
    tar -zxf $JDK_PACKAGE --strip-components 1  -C $JAVA_HOME  && \
    rm -f $JDK_PACKAGE

############################################
###  Install elastic search
############################################

# Base image stage 2
From ubuntu as es

#ARG JAVA_HOME
ARG ES_HOME
ARG ES_PACKAGE

WORKDIR /opt/

## download es
#  ADD https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.10.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz  /
#  ADD $JDK_PACKAGE /
COPY $ES_PACKAGE .

RUN mkdir -p $ES_HOME/  && \
    tar -zxf $ES_PACKAGE --strip-components 1  -C $ES_HOME  && \
    rm -f $ES_PACKAGE

# Mount elasticsearch.yml config
ADD config/elasticsearch.yml /opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

############################################
###  final
############################################

From ubuntu as finalbuild

ARG JAVA_HOME
ARG ES_HOME
ARG ES_PACKAGE

WORKDIR /opt/

# get artifacts from previous stages
COPY --from=jdk $JAVA_HOME $JAVA_HOME
COPY --from=es  $ES_HOME   $ES_HOME

# Setup JAVA_HOME, this is useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME $JAVA_HOME
ENV ES_HOME $ES_HOME

# setup paths
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
ENV PATH $PATH:$ES_HOME/bin

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 9300

# Define mountable directories.
#VOLUME ["/data"]


## give permission to entire elasticsearch setup directory
RUN useradd newuser --create-home --shell /bin/bash  && \
    echo 'newuser:newpassword' | chpasswd && \
    chown -R newuser $ES_HOME $JAVA_HOME  && \
    chown -R newuser:newuser /home/newuser && \
    chmod 755 /home/newuser
    #chown -R newuser:newuser /home/newuser
    #chown -R newuser /home/newuser  && \

USER newuser

WORKDIR /home/newuser

#RUN  chown -R newuser /home/newuser

#RUN apt-get update && \
#    apt-get install -yq curl

# Define default command.
CMD ["elasticsearch"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of docker is that you have tons of out-of-the-box images ready for you!

Why do you want to build your own `Dockerfile` for a common tech like Elasticsearch?

Why not simply:

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
```

and you have the image ready locally for run?

You can read more about running Elasticseach with docker [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#_pulling_the_image).

BTW, this image size is ~774MB

**EDIT:**

If it's for learning purpose, I can recommend [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) which can analyze baked images (like the `elasticsearch:7.10.1` and shows you each step of the image build (in other words, the `dockerfile` that built that image) and the base image it start FROM.

Comment: My bad , should have added this at the top of the problem description.   Already played with default elastic search image, But the purpose of this exercise is to learn working of Dockerfile. That is how i noticed my image being much larger (2.5G) than official image (742 M).

Comment: @coredump see my EDIT in the answer

Comment: @coredump did it answer your question? if yes, can you please accept/upvote the answer? if no, let me know if I can assist more

Comment: Thanks for pointing to Dive. Amazing tool .

Comment: @coredump no problem - can you please accept the answer if it helped? :)